# Do assembly languages differ among CPUs?

Tags: assembly, cpu

I'm interested in learning assembly. Basically I want to know if there are different languages (assembly) between different CPUs. If I had a modern Intel x86 processor, and an Intel x86 processor from a year ago would the assembly code by compatible across those two machines? Could I run that code on both machines without having to learn an entire other book of assembly instructions?

Comment: From time to time the same family of processors (x68 for example) will add new instructions or features that were not in a prior version.  And sometimes instructions are removed or changed or limited.  so it is possible to have to learn the differences.

Comment: x86 is a horrible first instruction set, hardly worth bothering to learn ever.  having the hardware is the the most common and yet worst excuse I have heard to try to learn x86 first.  Use a simulator and learn a good instruction set, msp430, pdp11, arm, thumb, even mips although I wouldnt learn that one first for different reasons.  avr, cant think of another first instruction set, I normally have a longer list.

Comment: @dwelch, being able to at least *read* Intel assembly can come in pretty handy when trying to debug crazytown problems or hunt down optimizer bugs.  And if you want a job writing boot ROMs for Intel machines, you don't have much choice....

Comment: there is not much work for writing intel boot roms not as much work as there is for arm, avr, 8051, mips, etc.  Intel based divices are so few as to not exist as far as processors go.  Once you learn one or a few good instruction sets then you can very quickly read most others, including x86.  Start off on the wrong foot though and the person usually just gives up and finds another hobby, assuming that all experiences are going to be similar to that one.

Comment: Yup, I'd agree with that.  I definitely would also recommend learning something other than x86 to start with.  I just think that x86 is a lot higher up the list than 'hardly worth bothering to learn ever'.

Comment: as far as x86 goes, one of many reasons for their success is backwards compatibility.  never a guarantee but todays instructions should continue to work on some or many generations of chips into the future, usually things are added and few if any are removed, it is almost never the case that you have to learn a whole new book of instructions, certainly not with x86.  you might, if you choose learn the new two or three or you can just stick with the old ones you know and like and not bother with the new instructions

Comment: both with my work and my hobbies I deal a lot with assembly and machine code for a number of architectures, always disassembling and analyzing.  Other than helping folks on SO with specific questions it has been 1-2 decades since I have needed to disassemble x86 code, and I use several x86 based systems to cross-develop for all other platforms.   I was a bit strong on the language, trying to get the point across.

Comment: When x86 for example went from a 16 bit architecture to 32, there were many changes, reading of new books.  multicore, more stuff to read, and 64 bit, more stuff to read.  But it is not a complete do over, much of the 16 bit instruction set still works, might require a special mode of the processor for the machine code, but knowledge learned at that time is still useful and valid today.  The 32 bit extensions as far as instructions go, just added a 32 bit kludge onto the existing 16 bit stuff, same with 64 bit, everything known from the past on x86 is more relevant than not.

Comment: Assembly language is not standardized and can differ even between different assemblers and compilers targeting the same CPU (compare MASM/TASM with NASM and (G)AS).

Comment: Really? Why would we vote this down? What's the point? There's nothing wrong that I can see wrong with this question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I had a modern Intel x86 processor, and an Intel x86 processor from a year ago would the assembly code by compatible across those two machines?

Yes, almost certainly.  Silicon vendors try to keep their instruction sets relatively stable in order to make life easier on the compiler writers and software developers in general.  Every once in a while some new instructions crop up, or some old ones stop working.  But it doesn't happen very often, especially on Intel.

> Could I run that code on both machines without having to learn an entire other book of assembly instructions?

Again, almost certainly yes.  But there are always exceptions.  You might find the [Intel Software Developers Manuals](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) to be interesting reading.

Comment: Could you give us an example of an instruction that stopped working?

Comment: @StenPetrov, "stopped working" is probably overstating things, but it's certainly possible.  As an example, ARM `stm` has deprecated inclusion of the stack pointer in the register set to be pushed (in ARMv6 or v7, can't remember which).

Comment: Link: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/Cihcadda.html

Comment: @StenPetrov POP CS on 8086, MOV to/from a test register on 80386, LOADALL(286) on 80286/80386. You don't have them any more.

Comment: @Sten Petrov The 8086 had a short version of 'INC <reg>' that took 1 byte instead of 2. AMD deprecated it in order to implement 64 bits. Even this small change was a big deal.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.

The assemblers for the Linux operating system for wildly differing processors all lean on GNU convention, and so are the same. They "only" differ in the actual CPU instructions. They have the same conventions regarding labels, comment and directives.

Now the opposite view is that the actual CPU instructions are the essential difference between assembler languages. This hinges on the properties of the cpu such as the names of registers and what operations are provided. The description of a modern Intel processor is a multi tome book, running thousands of pages in total. Likewise the description of Risc V is hundreds of pages, and there is no coordination with Intel. For an other processor you can expect an unrelated point of view and even conflicting terms.

If you think this is silly, I can tell you that it is not really less effort to rework an assembler program for Linux from say i86 to arm, than to rework an assembler program for Linux i86 (gas) to MS-Windows i86 (masm). See also an extensive family of non-trivial programs in
https://github.com/albertvanderhorst/ciforth.

Comment: Not quite true about comments; in GAS, the comment character depends on the ISA.  e.g. `#` for x86, `@` for ARM.  (With ARM using `#` as part of the decorator for immediates, like `adds r0, #1`)

Comment: @Peter Cordes They both took the wrong choice for comment signs. Everybody knows that the proper comment sign for assembly language is ';'   :-)  This doesn't really invalidate what I said. I had to paint with a wide brush for such a general question.

Comment: Right, agreed with your overall point.  (Unsure about it being less work to port from x86 Linux to ARM Linux than GAS to MASM, though; automated tools like assembler + disassembler can help there.  It's a bit unfair to include the cost of also having to port OSes: I/O and other system calls, and calling conventions at least for library functions, if not necessarily calls to your own functions.  That's all separate from syntax and would apply even if you used GAS on Windows.  GAS -> NASM on Linux might be a better example, which can be done with assemble + disas with objconv, copy comments.)